# C# Unable to cast object of type OldName to NewName

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have a problem when I cast list of object to the specific class, but I already moved MenuGroup class to other namespaces and rename to "VM_MenuGroup". It works perfectly on localhost but when I deployed to production I got the error like the image below.

[image]

**Code for assign VM_MenuGroup to Session**

```
 private void SetMenuSession(string role)
    {
        // TODO : Get data from databae
        List<VM_MenuGroup> menuGroups = new List<VM_MenuGroup>();
        if (role == "2")
        {
            menuGroups = GetManagerMenu();
        }
        else if (role == "3" || role == "4")
        {
            menuGroups = GetUserInventory();
        }
        else if (role == "5")
        {
            menuGroups = GetITMenu();
        }

        Session["USER_MENU"] = menuGroups;
    }
```

**Error occured on this code**

```
@using KenberStockManagement.Entities.ViewModel
```

```
    <li class="nav-small-cap">Home</li>
    @if (Session["USER_MENU"] != null)
    {
        var menuGroup = (List<VM_MenuGroup>)Session["USER_MENU"];

        if (Session["ROLE"].ToString() != "3" && Session["ROLE"].ToString() != "4")
        {
            <li>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i><span class="hide-menu">Dashboard </span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </li>
        }

        foreach (var menu in menuGroup)
        {

            <li>
                <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false"><i class="ti-package"></i><span class="hide-menu">@menu.mgName</span></a>
                @if (menu.subMenu.Count > 0)
                {
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                        @foreach (var subMenu in menu.subMenu)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@subMenu.url"><i class="@menu.icon">&nbsp;</i>@subMenu.mgName</a></li>

                        }
                    </ul>
                }
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </li>

        }
    }


</ul>
```

Comment: At a guess, it looks like you have deployed the compiled files correctly.  Have you cleared down what was there previously before copying your published files over?

Comment: Yes, I deleted all files before deploy to production.